# Sum of Squares in terms of Sum of Integers

Tags: summation

We know that the sum of squares can be expressed as a multiple of the sum of integers as follows: $$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n r^2
&=\frac 16 n(n+1)(2n+1)\\
&=\frac {2n+1}3\cdot \frac {n(n+1)}2\\
&=\frac {2n+1}3\sum_{r=1}^nr\end{align}$$

Is there a simple direct proof to express the sum of squares as $\dfrac {2n+1}3$ multiplied by the sum of integers, without first deriving the formula for the sum of squares and then breaking it down as shown above?

Comment: Possibly not what you are looking for but $$\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} r\right)^2-1 = \sum_{r=1}^n (r^3+3r^2+3r+1) = \left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)^2 + 3\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 + 3\sum_{r=1}^n r + n$$ seems a way ..

Comment: That might be a possible lead. Can you develop it further?

Comment: @hypergeometric Summation by parts seems to do the trick.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Have found a proof which does not require prior knowledge of the result of the sum of integers (or the sum of squares) - posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Solution**

Have just found a proof which does not require the prior knowledge of the result of the sum of integers.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i(2j-1)&& ...(1)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2(n-i)+1&& ...(2)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i 2(i-j)+1&& ...(3)\\
(1)+(2)+(3):\\
3\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i (2j-1)+2(n-1)+1+2(i-j)+1\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i (2n+1)\\
&=(2n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i\\
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2&=\frac{2n+1}3\sum_{i=1}^n i\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

This proof is a transcription of the diagrammatic proof of the same as shown on the wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number#Derivation_of_the_summation_formula).

See also the nice diagrams in this solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/663527).

---

**Earlier post shown below**

This is too long for a comment so it's being posted in the solution section.

A synthetic and rather cumbersome approach might be as follows:

$$\begin{align}
(2m+1)\sum_{r=1}^mr-(2m-1)\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}r
&=(2m+1)\frac {m(m+1)}2-(2m-1)\frac{m(m-1)}2\\
&=\frac m2\left[(2m+1)(m+1)-(2m-1)(m-1)\right]\\
&=3m^2\end{align}$$
Summing $m$ from $1$ to $n$ and telescoping LHS gives

$$(2n+1)\sum_{r=1}^nr=3\sum_{m=1}^nm^2\color{lightgray}{=3\sum_{r=1}^n r^2}\\
\sum_{r=1}^nr^2=\frac {2n+1}3\sum_{r=1}^nr\qquad\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Summation by Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Statement), with $f_r=r^2$ and $g_r=r$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n r^2&=(n+1)^3-1-\sum_{r=1}^n (r+1)\left((r+1)^2-r^2\right)\\\\
&=(n+1)^3-1-\sum_{r=1}^n (r+1)\left(2r+1\right)\\\\
&=(n+1)^3-1-2\sum_{r=1}^n r^2-3\sum_{r=1}^{n}r-\sum_{r=1}^{n}1\\\\
3\sum_{r=1}^n r^2&=(n+1)^3-1-3\sum_{r=1}^{n}r-\sum_{r=1}^{n}1\\\\
\sum_{r=1}^n r^2&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{2(n+2)}{3}-\sum_{r=1}^{n}r\\\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\left(\frac{2(n+2)}{3}-1\right)\\\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\frac{2n+1}{3}
\end{align}$$

---

**ALTERNATIVE SUMMATION BY PARTS**

We can instead use the [Newton Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Newton_series) for summation by parts.  Here, we let $f_k=g_k=k$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2&=n\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k} k\\\\
&=n\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-\sum_{k =0}^{n-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\\\\
&=(n+1)\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-\frac12\sum_{k =1}^n k(k+1)\\\\
\frac32\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2&=(n+1)\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-\frac12\sum_{k =1}^n k\\\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2&=\frac23 (n+1)\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-\frac13\sum_{k =1}^n\,k\\\\
&=\frac13(2n+1)\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

again as expected!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It appears to be similar to the textbook proof of summing $$(r+1)^3-r^3=3r^2+3r+1$$ for $r=1$ to $n$ and allowing LHS to telescope, resulting immediately in $$(n+1)^3-1^3=3\sum r^2+3\sum r+n$$.

Comment: @hypergeometric Yes, I am aware of the telescoping sum approach.  But summation by parts is more robust and does provide the decomposition.  I am happy to delete if this doesn't help.

Comment: Please leave the solution here. It helps to have different approaches.

Comment: @hypergeometric Great!  I also added an alternative solution using Newton's Series for summation by parts.  It might be a bit closer to what you're seeking.