# Work out the values of a and b (in the below question):

Tags: linear-algebra

$1^2 = 1$

$1^2 + 2^2 = 5$

$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 14$

$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 30$

$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + ...... + n^2 = an^3 + bn^2 + (n/6)$

Work out the values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=0}^nr^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
now you can expand this

Comment: just a question.

Comment: shouldn't r start with 1?

Comment: Possibly yes, although in this context the $r=0$ term is ignored obviously

Answer (score 0):

By one of the properties of sigma, the last equation can be expressed as $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

This means that the sum of the squares of numbers from $1$ to $n$ can be expressed as $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Therefore, you just have to make it equal to that and work out the values of $a$ and $b$ by yourself.

To be more clear, you just need to let $an^3+bn^2+\frac{n}{6}= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and solve for $n$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still have a few doubts though. How will solving for n get the values for a and b? And is it possible to get the values for a and b without using sigma?

Comment: 1^2+2^2+.....+n^2=an^3+bn^2+n/6=n(n+1)(2n+1)6                                             Is it better to understand?In case you are curious about how the formula is made, you can copy and go to this link.                  
                                        
                                        
 http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56920.html .                               
                                                                                                                   This shows you how the formula is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of squares of first $n$ natural numbers is [given by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122546/gaussian-proof-for-the-sum-of-squares) : $$ \Sigma_{r=1}^nr^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
Expanding it: $$\frac13 n^3+\frac 12 n^2+\frac n6$$

> So, $$a=\frac 13$$ and $$b=\frac 12$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is it possible to get the values of a and b without using sigma?

Comment: We used sigma to get that expression. Once got that, then just simplify it to form a cubic. And you are done!