# Integer solutions of k(k+1)/2=m^2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When I was solving the problem,

"Prove that there are infinity integer solutions for $x^2-2y^2=1$"

I did this kind of thing:

Since x is odd and y is even, let $x=2k+1$ and $y=2m$
then we get $k(k+1)/2=m^2$.

Since there are infinity amount of integers for $x^2-2y^2=1$,

we result that k(k+1)/2=m^2 has infinity amount of integer solutions.

I think we can prove that k(k+1)/2=m^2 has infinity amount of integer solutions in some way.

(Sum of 1~k) = (m^2)   --->  this looks kind of cool

My question is :

"Prove that $k(k+1)/2=m^2$ has infinitely many integer solutions. (without using $x^2-2y^2=1$)"

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "Let $x=2k+1$ and $y=2m$ then we get $k(k+1)/2=m^2$". So $k^2+k=2m^2$. This is just rewriting Pell.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the comment.  Btw I'm curious if (sum of 1~k)=(m^2) has some kind of algebraic or combinational meaning.

Comment: The sum of consecutive integers has a combinatorial meaning, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081649/understanding-some-proofs-without-words-for-sums-of-consecutive-numbers-consecu), but that this is again a square has an algebraic meaning - again given by Pell's equation and its algebraic solution. So we are back again.